# useEffect does not run a named setInterval

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, setinterval

I have a component that accept $nextUpdateDatTime (the time with the date when the component should be updated). And useEffect doesn't want to run either setInterval or setTimeout. If I remove the name setTimeout(or setInterval), it fires, but only once, after which it does not fire. I tried to move this functionality to the parent component and transfer seconds via props - the result is exactly the same. BUT if I change something in the component code and save it (for example, add console.log), then the timer starts working! But as soon as I refresh the page, useEffect does not see and does not run setInterval(setTimeout) again.

Code:

```
interface IMinutesRemainingProps {
    $nextUpdateDateTime: string;
}

function MinutesRemaining({
    $nextUpdateDateTime}: IMinutesRemainingProps) {

    const [secondsToUpdate, setSecondsToUpdate] = useState(0);
    
    const changeMinutesToUpdate = () => {
        const currentDateTime = new Date().getTime();
        const nextUpdate = new Date($nextUpdateDateTime).getTime();
        
        setSecondsToUpdate(Math.round((nextUpdate - currentDateTime) / (1000)));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('mount')
        const updateRespawnInterval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('interval')
            changeMinutesToUpdate();
        }, 1000);
        
        return () => {
            console.log('unmount')
            clearInterval(updateRespawnInterval);
        }
    }, [secondsToUpdate])

    return (
        <Minutes>
            ⟳ {secondsToUpdate}s
        </Minutes>
    );
}
```

console logs:
mount
unmount
mount

I tried to remove the return, I tried to remove the dependency array or leave it empty. I also tried to move all the functionality to the parent component and transfer seconds via props - none of this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

interface IMinutesRemainingProps {
  nextUpdateDateTime: string;
}

function MinutesRemaining({ nextUpdateDateTime }: IMinutesRemainingProps) {
  const [secondsToUpdate, setSecondsToUpdate] = useState<number>(() => {
    //add currentDateTime to have right calculation from current time
    const currentDateTime = new Date().getTime();
    const nextUpdate = new Date(nextUpdateDateTime).getTime();
    return Math.round((nextUpdate - currentDateTime) / 1000);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateRespawnInterval = setInterval(() => {
      changeMinutesToUpdate();
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(updateRespawnInterval);
    };
  }, []);

  const changeMinutesToUpdate = () => {
    setSecondsToUpdate((prevSeconds) => {
       //decrease by 1 each second
      if (prevSeconds > 0) {
        return prevSeconds - 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  };

  return <div>⟳ {secondsToUpdate}s</div>;
}

export default MinutesRemaining;
```

Set a property:

```
<MinutesRemaining nextUpdateDateTime="2024-01-22T12:00:00" />
```

Comment: it doesn't work, the interval is triggered only once

Comment: for me works well.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you, but what could be the reason it doesn't work for me?

Comment: I don't see what are you doing)

Comment: https://github.com/bynilow/rpg_game/blob/master/src/components/Pages/Area/UpdatedMinutes/MinutesRemaining.tsx
here is the problematic component

Comment: send me the email address I created for you code-sandbox

Comment: bynilow@mail.ru

Comment: Add secondsToUpdate into the dependency array.

useEffect(() => {
        console.log('mount')
        const updateRespawnInterval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('interval')
            changeMinutesToUpdate();
        }, 1000);

        return () => {
            console.log('unmount')
            clearInterval(updateRespawnInterval);
        }
    }, [secondsToUpdate]);

Comment: it doesn't help, it's not about useEffect or setInterval, it's about something else

Comment: Your component works just fine, so maybe it is something else, not your component. Try to create a standalone repro in a repl environment.